# 3314 on a combobox with autocomplete in access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have created a combo box ("product" field) to autofill other fields ("product code" and "boxes") in a subform. I use in "on change event" this code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub PRODUCTO_Change()
Me.CODIGO.Value = Me.PRODUCTO.Column(1)
Me.CAJAS.Value = Me.PRODUCTO.Column(2)
End Sub
```

But when I make a mistake typing the word and the autocomplete function mismatches, or when I try to correct with backspace, an error window pops up telling "Run-time error "3314": you must enter a value in the "productos pedidos.codigo" field where "codigo" is a primary key of one of my database tables.

I tried deleting the subform and creating it again, changing the field names, but the issue persists. I can just select the product searching the word whit the scrollbar in the list without autocomplete, but I have nearly 200 hundred diferent products and I need the autocomplete function.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I try to type the product´'s name in combobox field, but I can`t type anything. It`s like the autocomplete works but the record can't be saved and keeps blank but the code field is autofilled.

Comment: I would use AfterUpdate event instead. I have never used Change event. Why do you need to duplicate CODIGO and CAJAS into another table?

Comment: It worked!, thanks so much! What do you mean? I have "cajas" only in one table, but I need codigo in two tables because I created a relationship between my table "productos" and my table "productos-pedidos"

Comment: If CAJAS value (Column(2)) is coming from same table as PRODUCTO, where are you saving it to with this code? What is value of Column(0)? Isn't this the key? Why would there be a link on CODIGO? If you are happy with results, then go with it. I am just confused by data structure and relationships from little info provided.

Comment: Im saving combobox data in a table called "productos-pedidos", it has 2 primary keys to join to "Productos" table (primary key "codigo", the product code) and "Pedidos" table ("primary key "indentificador", the order code). The combobox source comes from "Productos". It's the first time I make a database with different tables, so I don't know if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Still doesn't sound right but this isn't appropriate forum to discuss. Good luck with project.